# Conclusion of scatter plots

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have graphed two data sets, each with the same y-values but the two data sets have different x-values. I have graphed them and one had a positive correlation, while the other had no correlation.
in the x-axis I was given to label MPQ and in the y I was given to label T450. The question was whether increasing levels of MPQ had also increased levels of T450. Then what would the reasonable overall conclusion be?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I know this is more like science but I wasn't sure where to post it since it had to do with scatter plots

Comment: An image of the plots could be helpful

Comment: I added it now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reasonable conclusion would be to say:

There was a positive linear association between MPQ and T450 in the first dataset, while no linear association was found between these variables in the second dataset.

Answer (score 2):

"The question was whether increasing levels of MPQ had also increased levels of T450."

Since the two datasets have two statistically differing outcomes, the only correct answer would involve separating the two cases:

For dataset A, since there is a positive correlation between the two variables, increasing levels of MPQ correspond to increasing levels of T450.

For dataset B, since there is no correlation between the two variables, increasing levels of MPQ do not result in a statistically significant increase in levels of T450.